# Magisk how to hide completely Magisk Manager and Unhide Magisk

Tags: magisk

I configuring  mobile for my Mom, how do I hide Magisk Manager completely. I don't wanna see this app. All I need is to unhide it from ssh session or from adb.

Comment: 1. From Magisk Manager settings you can change the app name to anything you like, it can even have[icons instead of letters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpJ6r.jpg) and 2 the Package name is randomized 3.  If you want your mom to not even see this, use a launcher that let's you hide apps like Nova 4. I haven't checked with adb /ssh though

Comment: 1 & 2 are more relevant if you are trying to hide Magisk from root detecting apps like banking etc. 3 is just to ensure your mom wouldn't see that. If you use launcher hiding as suggested, I am sure adb/ssh will have no problems (though I haven't tested)

Comment: [Hide apps using Nova](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/nova-launcher-101-hide-apps-remove-icons-free-up-space-your-app-drawer-0179914/)